# Rails magic ; and <=>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine-plugins

I'm new to Rails and I'm studying Redmine. I see 2 magic function definitions as below:

1.

```
  def to_s; name end
```

and 2.

```
  def <=>(tracker)
    position <=> tracker.position
  end
```

I cannot understand, please explain what is ";" in "to_s;" and what is "<=>"

Thank you

Comment: btw, 1 has no magic, its just a method written on one line, and `;` is used as separator

Comment: Hint: `def foo` defines a method named `foo`. `def bar` defines a method named `bar`. `def <=>` defines a method named … can you guess?

Comment: `<=>` is the comparison operator for performing sorts. If you have a collection of these and call sort it will use this method to compare the two objects.